# WPF .NET: OpenSubkey() don't find value in registry

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, registry

I've created some values in Windows Registry and try to access them from .NET but there is an error.

Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE").OpenSubKey("ZvezdnyShop") is null, however there is an such key in Registry

[REGEDIT http://astzvezdny.newsujet.com/REGEDIT.jpg](http://astzvezdny.newsujet.com/REGEDIT.jpg)
[ERROR IN VS http://astzvezdny.newsujet.com/VS.jpg](http://astzvezdny.newsujet.com/VS.jpg)

What's the matter?

**ANSWER**

My Application was 32bit, so I need place ZvezdnyShop at HKLM/Software/Wow6432Node
Thanks to Frédéric Hamidi

Comment: Maybe your application targets the x86 platform? The `ZvezdnyShop` key in your screenshot resides in the 64-bit portion of the registry, so a 32-bit application won't see it unless it also exists under the `Wow6432Node` key.

Comment: @Frédéric Should have been an answer

Comment: @Soumya92, you're probably right. I posted that as a comment because it had a question inside, but now I guess an answer is necessary so the question is properly resolved. I'll do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `ZvezdnyShop` key in your screenshot resides in the [64-bit portion of the registry](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/896459), so it will only be visible to 64-bit applications.

Therefore, if your project targets the `x86` platform, the 32-bit application it produces won't see that key.

To fix that problem, you can create the key in the 32-bit portion of the registry, i.e. `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\ZvezdnyShop`, or have your project target the `x64` platform.